# Fast aproach to modifying a const char* array

Tags: c++, performance, pointers, networking, winpcap

I am working with Winpcap library and I am facing a performance problem.
When I call to

```
pcap_next_ex(fp, &header, &pkt_data)
```

I get a const char* array with the packet data at `pkt_data`.

Now I want to modify some part of it, so I figured out this way:

```
std::vector<char> send_pkt(pkt_data, pkt_data + header->caplen);
```

(header->caplen being the packet length) And now I can play with it, and send it down.

But, I got network delays up to 2000 ms, so I profiled the code at VS 2013, and it seems like that line of code is eating too much cpu cycles. I suppose it is because the packet array is copied entirely to the vector.

So my question is, what can I do to modify the original `const char *pkt_data` array in a fast way?

Thank you very much!

EDIT: Finally solved the problem. The winpcap driver was causing all the trouble, because it had the mintocopy property set too high (16000 by default), so with low traffic, like running a ping, the buffer didn't get full, and generated the delay.
Calling to `pcap_setmintocopy(fp, 10)` did the trick.

For the packet (const char *) modifying, I used the casting solution provided below with success, in spite of the risk of modifying something marked as a constant, It worked and now I accomplished the objective perfectly.

```
u_char * send_pkt = const_cast<u_char *>(pkt_data);
```

Comment: Why do you need copy that data? What about operating on the original data?

Comment: So you want to modify which is _const_ ?

Comment: you shall not modify anything behind a `const char*`.

Comment: I don't intrinsically need to copy that data, I only need to modify it, but, since it's a const variable, its the only thing I thought of. I am asking for a better approach. Thanks.

Comment: "And now I can play with it, and send it down." - what API are you using to send?  If it's some kind of streaming API then perhaps you can track where your modifications are to be, then send the prior data directly from the original buffer, your alternative data from wherever it is, and any trailing data from the original buffer?

Comment: It's the Winpcap function `int pcap_sendpacket(pcap_t *, const u_char *, int)` so no luck

Comment: It's possible that the heap allocation/deallocation peformed by `vector` is significant performance wise - you could try using a `char buffer[MAX_PACKET_SIZE + 1];` to copy `pkt_data` to, or just make sure you keep the `vector` around between packets so its capacity works as a high water mark.

Comment: `char send_pkt[1000];
memcpy(send_pkt, pkt_data, header->caplen);
`
I tried that as said in below comments and show only a little improvement. Thanks

Comment: Anyway, given packets can't be huge (they could be more than 1000 bytes though!), a 2000ms delay is totally crazy - way more than any allocation or copying time.  I think you're doing something else slow and whatever profiling points at this line is misleading.

Comment: Well, put 1000 bytes and testing with ping, so no problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll go ahead and speak the unspeakable:  you could cast away const from the pointer, and then modify the data.  Of course by doing so you will be entering the realm of Undefined Behavior, and thereby introducing the possibility of crashes, incorrect results, Flying Nose Daemons, etc.  But the compiler will allow you to do it, so if you're desperate and nothing else is sufficient, you could give it a try and see what happens.  Keep in mind that even if it seems to work on your machine, that doesn't imply it will necessarily work on other platforms.

Before doing anything rash, though, I'd first try this:  permanently allocate a large-enough char array, memcpy() the const string into said array, and modify the array however you need to.  memcpy() is quite efficient, since (unlike your vector approach) it does not require any dynamic allocation or freeing of memory from the heap.  See if that is fast enough for you.

Comment: If nothing else, the fact that the library deliberately exposes the data as `const` suggests that it's more than just tempting fate: you're almost guaranteed to really f@*& something up! I do like your idea of keeping the copy but losing the repetitive allocation.

Comment: How can I exactly cast away the const?

Comment: Another thought:  email the author(s) of said library and ask them what they suggest.  It may be that it is safe to modify the data directly, and if so they might be willing to add a non-const-returning version of the function to the library.  Or if not they might suggest some other approach; I'd imagine this issue isn't too uncommon for this library's use cases.

Comment: +1 we were all thinking it ;-).  @LightnessRacesinOrbit: well, if the data modified includes e.g. sequence numbers that might not be copied elsewhere and could be used by the pcap code as it processes the data further, verifies incoming data etc, then yeah - but there's probably also lots of non-meta-data data in there that's only a problem if checksummed.  The OP should have a feel for what kind of damage they might do.

Comment: char * imFeelingLucky = const_cast<char *>(ptr);  // and may god have mercy on your soul ;)

Comment: My concern here is that the OP appears so mired in an XY problem that he's going to take your `const_cast` and not pay attention to any of the rest of it. :(

Comment: Lightness, please, dont be so rude, I love to program in C++, although only been tought C at University, so, please, calm down, I understood immediately what Jeremy wrote, indeed, I used const_cast some lines before in my program ;)

Comment: That's entirely possible -- but he can't say he hasn't been warned, and if/when he gets bit by it later on, it will be a valuable life lesson.  Or something like that.  (yes, I know I'm rationalizing the corruption of our youth ;))

Comment: Well, tried casting the const away and.... nothing happens, my program not even starts... so fail. :(( I know, Undefined Behavior

Comment: @Dark_eye Edit your attempt into the question. It could be something you did wrong, or easily dismissed as undefined behavior rearing its unspeakable face.

Comment: @Dark_eye: `I understood immediately what Jeremy wrote` and `I used const_cast some lines before in my program` contradict each other. :( Still I'm perfectly calm (but, er, thanks?! I guess) and I'm sorry if you thought I was rude.

Comment: @remyabel Yes, I left the profiling options enabled, so, took so much time loading symbols that I tought it was hanged.
Tried both methods, casting away const, and memcpying, and both show a light improvement, but still 1900 ms delay...

Comment: Smill nit pick - Big U / Big B "Undefined Behaviour" is normally used to refer to behaviours that the C++ Standard itself says are undefined.  There's nothing to tell us whether casting away const here is Undefined Behaviour in that technical sense... we only know it's disrespecting the pcap API, but the buffer behind is almost certainly valid initialised memory that's legal to write to from a C++ language sense - the question is whether the pcap library will consequently spin out of control and invoke wrong or Undefined behaviour somehow....

Answer (score 1):

> what can I do

**Nothing.** You shall not modify anything behind a `const char*`.

> I suppose it is because the packet array is copied entirely to the vector.

Yes, probably. If you want to modify data, you need to own it, and in this scenario unless you copy it you do not own it.

Comment: You know, they are IP packets: Quite a lot bytes and very often, so, copying them is terribly slow. I hope there's a better way...

Comment: @Dark_eye: A better way to do _what_? You never told us.

Comment: A better way to perform changes to the result of the pcap_next_ex function, which are stored in that const char* variable. I know, that I cannot directly change a const char*, but must be a fast way to achieve the final objective.

Comment: @Dark_eye: No, what are you trying to _do_? What _is_ your final objective? Modifying data that (a) does not belong to you, and (b) is marked `const` cannot be your final objective!

Comment: I think is clear enough from title and post, but, again.
1. Get the data from the function
2. Do some conversion/copy/whatever on the const char* variable
3. Eventually modify the data

Comment: I messed up with the intro key, I edited the comment to be correct sorry

Comment: @Dark_eye: I don't think you're hearing me. I'm asking you to tell us _what you want to do_ at a higher level. That is, **why** do you think you need to modify that data? For what purpose? What is the goal of your code? My instinct at the moment is that you are wedged waist-deep in an XY problem.

Comment: Ok, I am modifying the source MAC address of the packet, and the sending the modified one through the net.

Comment: @Dark_eye: Finally! :) Do you mind if I ask why you're MAC spoofing?

Comment: Yes, you guessed it, that's the reason not to saying it, this Question should be about C++ not Networking. But this time I am the good guy, and I only want to make some sort of protective proxy.

Comment: @Dark_eye If your goal is MAC spoofing, it would be easier to suggest an alternative to your intended approach if you think the solution is to modify a `const char*`. Of course on a library that doesn't expose a modifiable `char*`, you do what you have to do (aside from e-mailing the maintainer.) But by describing your original problem, better solutions than `cast the const away` can be given.

Comment: I think is simple, get the sniffed packet, and replace the source MAC with the proxy-server's one, so, the client original MAC is only know and stored by the proxy, replacing it back in the answer.

Comment: @Dark_eye: the danger with that is that the MAC address might be used by the pcap code or some networking drivers on the machine as some kind of key - changing the MAC might create a delay while another DNS lookup or some such is done - if it takes 2 seconds it probably has to be something that grossly inefficient.

Comment: It is supposed to be low level library, and I could bet it does not parse packet contents.